# How to link to boost in /usr/local compiling with clang++?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, clang, asio

I am not a pro in command line based compiling. I developed the below asio UDP application taking the code from [boost official example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime5.html).

```
// udpServer.cpp

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    udp::socket socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 13));

    for (;;)
    {
      std::array<char, 1> recv_buf;
      udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;
      boost::system::error_code error;
      socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf), remote_endpoint, 0, error);

      if (error && error != boost::asio::error::message_size)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error);

      std::string message = "some_string";

      boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
      socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), remote_endpoint, 0, ignored_error);
    }
  }

  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have boost 1.59 installed using Macports as this is the version I got doing `sudo port install boost`. I see that boost located in my `/usr/local/lib` & headers in `/usr/local/include`

I tried suggestions from other discussions, but the code does not compile as it is **not able to link to boost**. I am on OSX & trying to compile with clang with following command

```
clang++ -std=c++14 udpServer.cpp
```

*tried this*

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -I /usr/local/include/boost -L /usr/local/lib udpServer.cpp
```

But getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  boost::asio::error::get_system_category() in udpServer-4b9a12.o
  boost::system::error_code::error_code() in udpServer-4b9a12.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in udpServer-4b9a12.o
"boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init in udpServer-4b9a12.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in udpServer-4b9a12.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: why not use `homebrew`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -lboost_system udpServer.cpp -o updServer
```

You include header file as `<boost/asio.hpp>`, so just pass `-I /usr/local/include`. `-I` `-L` just let linker know where find headers and libraries. You also need let linker know what library you actually need to link through `-l<library_name>`.

By the way, `/usr/local/include` is default header search path, `/usr/local/lib` is default library search path. So you can just:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -lboost_system udpServer.cpp -o updServer
```

Comment: thanks a lot. thats what I needed. understand how this works now. yep